# WebAPI HttpPost take IFormFile and a model as input parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to create a method that uploads a file + takes an instance of a class\struct as an additional argument.

```
// Works
[HttpPost("test_1")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test1(IFormFile file) { return Ok(); }

public struct MyModel
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
}

// Doesn't work
[HttpPost("test_2")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test2(IFormFile file, MyModel model) { return Ok(); }
```

Calling `test_2` produces following result:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
  "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "status": 415,
  "traceId": "8000000c-0007-fd00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
```

How should I modify `test_2` method to produce required result?

Comment: You should also include how the request is being made

Answer (score 4):

Because your request contains multi part (file and optional data).
So change it to form-data and you can get them with **[FromForm]** on Api.
Try this

```cs
public struct MyModel
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Files { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost("test_2")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test2([FromForm]MyModel model) { return Ok(); }
```

Hope it helps